# jQuery consolidation and cleanup

Tags: jquery

What would be the best way to write a much cleaner version of this. I have some ideas but would love a second opinion here.

```
$('.screenshot1').click(function(){
    $('#screenshot1').show();
});
$('.screenshot2').click(function(){
  $('#screenshot2').show();
});
$('.screenshot3').click(function(){
  $('#screenshot3').show();   
});
$('.screenshot4').click(function(){
  $('#screenshot4').show();
});
  $('.screenshot5').click(function(){
    $('#screenshot5').show();
  });
$('.screenshot6').click(function(){
  $('#screenshot6').show();   
});
$('.screenshot7').click(function(){
  $('#screenshot7').show();   
});
$('#screenshot1, #screenshot2, #screenshot3, #screenshot4, #screenshot5, #screenshot6, #screenshot7, .modal-backdrop').click(function() {
  $('#screenshot1').hide();
  $('#screenshot2').hide();
  $('#screenshot3').hide();
  $('#screenshot4').hide();
  $('#screenshot5').hide();
  $('#screenshot6').hide();
  $('#screenshot7').hide();
});
```

HTML Looks like this:

```
<a class="screenshot1" href="#"></a>
<div id="screenshot1">
  <img src='homepage/screenshot1.jpg' alt='Screenshot 1' height='565' width='756' />
</div>
```

etc....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("[class^=screenshot]").click(function() {
      $('[id^="screenshot"]').hide();         
      var id = this.className.match(/screenshot(\d+)/)[1];
      $('#'+id).show()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show the specific screenshot though, it would show them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a single selector for all the screenshot IDs and then use the [each method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Edit: PSR's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="screenshot">
        <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Apply the same class to all your screenshots:

```
$('.screenshot').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.container'). find('.screenshot') .each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you mean, but I hope it helps in finding your right approach:

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[class^="screenshot"]').click(function(){
        // Hide them all
        $('[id^="screenshot"]').hide();

        // Show only the clicked one
        var id_name = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + id_name).show();
    });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: what does the [class^="listTest"] select?

Comment: Oops I forgot to replace the test name I used with `screenshot`. Did it now. Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify your first block of code by using the following,

```
$(".screenshot1, .screenshot2, .screenshot3, .screenshot4, .screenshot5, .screenshot6, .screenshot7").click(function(){ 
       $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fRHhh/2/)